# How to return values from ansible to jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, ansible, jenkins-pipeline

How to get some return values from ansible playbook to jenkins file??? I want to push customized status details from tasks in ansible to jenkins. Im using jenkins ansible plugin.Please help.

```
stage('Deploying and restarting the application') {
    withEnv(['ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=False']) {
        ansiblePlaybook credentialsId: 'cred',
                extras: "-e artifactName=${artifactName} -e artifactPath=${artifactPath} -e version=${version} -e packaging=${packaging}",
                installation: 'Ansible 2.1',
                inventory: 'ansible/Inventory',
                playbook: playbookPathHolder, sudoUser: null
 }
}
```

Comment: Just FYI, please c.f. [this bug ticket](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/19720) which indicates that the return codes are not always as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to make your playbook write the output into a file that Jenkins can then parse.

Inside ansible, you can serialize a variable into a file using the following filter:

```
{{ some_variable | to_nice_json(indent=2) }}
```

And from Jenkins you can deserialize the file into a JSON object using:

```
def ansibleOut = new JsonSlurper().parseText(inputFile.text)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, Is this the only option?? No direct ways??

Comment: The ansible plugin just executes the playbook the same way as running the playbook from the command line. Thus the only options are parsing console output :( or writing the output to a file.

Comment: Can you show how you would parse output in Jenkins?